# How to authorize correctly with Trello via OAuth?

Tags: oauth, postman, authorization, trello

I am trying to Authorize via OAuth with Trello and I can't seem to get it right, even in postman.

I have followed their API docs and have got myself a developer key and I have used a little link they have in [this article](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/authorization/) to get a valid auth token.

I tried including the API key and Auth token in the header and (in a separate test) in the body, as per their documentation.
[image: Header and Body auth guidance]

Everything I try results in "unauthorized permission requested".
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I had obviously made a mistake when trying the Header route.

It works now if I provide a header key called Authorization and the API key and Auth Token in the following format OAuth oauth_consumer_key="{{apiKey}}", oauth_token="{{apiToken}}".